# Get multiple values for one row on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, row, unpivot

I have a table with multiple dates and one ID and many strings. Each ID have multiple dates and strings, but only one ID.

I want to get all the dates value for one ID (for example ID=INI111) and get each date as a single value. I mean, I don't want all the dates on a single row, I want one row for each date. I want this too with the strings, but the important is the dates.

When I said "row" I mean to the results of the query.

For example:

Data:

> ID ----------- Date1 ---------- String1 ---------- Date2 ----------- String2 ----- Date3
>   ------- String 3 INI100-------  2020/02/02  ---- aaaaa -------- 2020/02/03  ------- bbbbb ---- 2020/02/04--cccccc

Output:

1. 2020/02/02
2. aaaaa
3. 2020/02/03
4. bbbbb
5. 2020/02/04
6. ccccc

Anyone can helps me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results, as tabular text. It is not that clear what you ask for.

Comment: I put an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to unpivot your dataset. In Postgres, you can do this with a lateral join:

```
select v.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral(
    values(id, date1::text), (id, string1), (id, date2::text), (id, string2)
) v(id, val)
```

Note that this requires adjusting the datatypes in the generated column (the query casts dates to strings).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=af8718d2e105cb52196da2af7c95dd2c)**:

```
id     | val       
:----- | :---------
INI100 | 2020-02-02
INI100 | aaaaa     
INI100 | 2020-02-03
INI100 | bbbbb
```

Comment: I get an error, it said that the types string and integer are not coincident

Comment: @Imrik: if you have non-string columns, you need to cast them to string beforehand, as shown in the query for dates.

Comment: ok, i cast all to strings, the result of the query is a lot of (INI100... INI101.... INI200...) and another null value on the other column

Comment: If I use a where clause 'where id ilike 'INI100' and I have only the number of columns that I really want, but the other values are null

Comment: @Imrik: I can't see your data. However, you can see in the db fiddle that I provided that the query produces the expected results for the sample data that you provided.